# How to get the image size in styled-components?

Tags: css, styled-components

When trying to display the image through:

```
import photo1 from "./path/photo1.jpg";

export const photo1 = styled.img`
  background: url(${photo1});
`;
```

the width is set to 0, and the height to the parents height. As such I am struggling to have the element scale according to the container as it seems to require hard coded sizes.

Using `background-size: contain` does not work automatically as the element still retains its starting *0 x 100%* size.
Only after hard coding a width the element displays properly contained, but that width will remain fixed causing problems when the container is later scaled.

**So how can I dynamically obtain the image original size to then have it scale according to the container?**

I am also considering if this makes sense at all to have the image dynamic and not just hard code the sizes and use several media queries along with equal number of pre-resized images.

---

On a side note, out of curiosity, anyone know what the math would be to scale the width and height maintaining the ratio only using `calc()`?

Comment: try `width: 100%;`

Comment: @LeoLima That locks the width to be the same as the container, but the original image does not match the containers ratio, orientation and I would want it smaller within the container.

Comment: got. you can add rule for positioning background: `background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;` for example. works for you? this will scale images to cover the container, positioning at center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just received the answer elsewhere, so for someone else that might be lost here's what I found out.

---

Because Styled-Components returns an html tag with the styles you added in it you can still use the standard html attributes like normal like you do when adding props. Example:

```
const Photo1 = styled.img`
  object-fit: contain;
`;

return (
  <Photo1 src="./path/photo1.jpg" />
)
```

The Photo1 element will use the `src=""` and thus receive the original sizing as opposed to before where it was creating an **empty** img tag and adding a background. The background is just a background and not the image with its sizing like it is when `src=""` is used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to fetch live properties values like this:

```js
$('.element.').property();

example

$('body').width();
```

would output the current width of the body tag element.